# forcibly launching an application

Tags: android, gps, location

Is it possible somehow to force launch my application in the background on Android when:

- GPS is turned on
  OR
- another app is opened?

What I want to achieve with this:
I have an app in which you can `buy parking ticket / highway ticket` etc... I want to have the location of the user as soon as it `starts any navigation app` so when he `parks or goes to the highway` I can send a notification to purchase ticket.
`The app already handles locations but only if it's open`.

Answer (score 1):

Now it's not possible to lunch application with forcely.

After **Android 6.0+** if you want to tract user **location**, storage etc! user must have to provide **permission**. Without that you can't do this.

And now for high sequrity patch, your app wont start **GPS is turned on OR another app is opened**. It's not possible now.

Thanks.